# Insert the whole vector<unique_ptr> as element in other vector

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I tried to define move constructor `Person(Person&&)` and delete default one `Person() = delete`, but I still get `std::unique_ptr<Person,std::default_delete<Person>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Person,std::default_delete<Person>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`.

I tried to manually iterate and move one item at a time, but this didn't help. What am I missing here?

**Attempt**

```
  v2.push_back(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>());
    for (const auto& p : v)
    {
        v2[0].push_back(std::move(p));
    }
```

**Code**

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    Person(std::string name) {}
};

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>> v;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>> v2;
    std::unique_ptr<Person> ptr1 = std::make_unique<Person>("name");

    v.push_back(std::move(ptr1));
    v2.push_back(v);
```

Comment: A unique_ptr cannot be copied, like the name says, and you are copying the vector of unique_ptrs 'v' to the vector of vectors of unique_ptrs 'v2'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here, one in each of your code snippets:

```
for (const auto& p : v)
{
    v2[0].push_back(std::move(p));
}
```

Get rid of the `const` - you can't move from a `const` object (or reference).

And:

```
v2.push_back(v);
```

will try to copy `v` (which you can't do, because of the `unique_ptr` aspect), so it needs to be:

```
v2.push_back(std::move(v));
```

(assuming that is your intent).

Comment: you're right, this will invoke the move version  `_Emplace_one_at_back(_STD move(_Val)`

Comment: Yeah, I always validate my answers at Wandbox to avoid screwing up :)